# how to translate the idiom 阴阳怪气?

Tags: idioms

Some has translated it into "say something with sarcasm", but it lost the connotation of the literal meaning of this idiom, the strange, unnatural, ugly-sounding and a bit sissy tone.

Answer (score 2):

> [eerie](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/eerie)
>
> *strange in a frightening and mysterious way*

阴阳怪气 describe "an unnatural tone or vibe" (doesn't sound/ feel like male or female)  I would translate it as "eerie vibe"

说话阴阳怪气 could be translated as "talk with an **eerie voice**"

这人阴阳怪气  could be translated as "this man **projects an eerie vibe**"

Comment: This sounds a lot better! but still a bit inaccurate with the horrific feeling. I was thinking more of the situation where one mocks some other in an unfriendly and mean way.

Comment: @XiaoxiongLin, don't agree this is better. It would be completely misunderstood to be "said in a strange voice/tone" but actually it is said in a normal tone but with sarcastic meaning.

Comment: @jf328I mean every word has a literal meaning and an extended meaning right? Sometimes you want to translate both so that to preserve more of the original feeling of text.